# Add a hyperlink to a HelloSign template

Tags: php, hellosign-api

I am using HelloSign with PHP SDK to send an agreement to users to sign. I need to add a link to 'Terms of Service' in the body of the signing document, so that users can click, visit the link and return to sign the document. I am using a PDF with a clickable hyperlink as the HelloSign template but HelloSign does not seem to support links on templates. The links appear as flat text and not clickable. How can I get this done in HelloSign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much for your question. I will be more than happy to assist you with this.

That is correct, all hyperlinks are removed from the documents. The url will be in shown in plain text but will not be clickable. This is the case for **ANY** signature request: non-embedded and embedded.

A suggested workaround for **non-embedded** signature requests is to add the link to the message body of the signature request.

Please let me know about any additional questions that you may have.

Thanks!

LaToya